# How to add custom field to category and query it?

Tags: php, wordpress

With this I add a custom field to a category:

```
add_action ( 'edit_category_form_fields', function( $tag ){
    $cat_title = get_term_meta( $tag->term_id, '_pagetitle', true ); ?>
    <tr class='form-field'>
        <th scope='row'><label for='cat_page_title'><?php _e('Category Page Title'); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='cat_title' id='cat_title' value='<?php echo $cat_title ?>'>
            <p class='description'><?php _e('Title for the Category '); ?></p>
        </td>
    </tr> <?php
});

add_action ( 'edited_category', function() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['cat_title'] ) )
        update_term_meta( $_POST['tag_ID'], '_pagetitle', $_POST['cat_title'] );
});
```

Then I try to add my own text with ajax:

```
  function data_person(){
    $catname = $_POST['catName'];
    $surnameCat = $_POST["surnameCat"];
    $cityCat = $_POST["cityCat"];
    $catDob = $_POST["dobCat"];
    $catBio = $_POST["catBio"];
    $cat_ID = get_cat_ID( sanitize_title_for_query($catname) );  
    // Check if category exists
    if($cat_ID == 0) {
        $cat_name = $catname;  
        $cat_sur = $surnameCat;
        $cat_city = $cityCat;  
        $cat_dob = $catDob;
        $cat_bio = $catBio;
        $cat_slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes($cat_name);
        $my_cat = array(
          'cat_name' => $cat_name, 
          'category_description' => $cat_bio, 
          'cat_title' => $cat_sur, 
          'category_nicename' => $cat_slug, 
          'category_parent' => 0
        );
        if( wp_insert_category( $my_cat ) ) {
          echo json_encode("Category added successfully");
        } else {
          echo json_encode("That category already exists");
        }
    } else {
      echo json_encode("That category already exists");
    }
    exit;
  }
```

but I am not sure how to add the text to the new created custom field, this isn't working: `'cat_title' => $cat_sur,` as it isn't saving the value I am sending from the input field once I click. Basically what should I put instead of `'cat_title' =>` ?

**UPDATE**

This is the full code, so in function.php we have:

```
add_action ( 'edit_category_form_fields', function( $tag ){
    $cat_title = get_term_meta( $tag->term_id, '_pagetitle', true ); ?>
    <tr class='form-field'>
        <th scope='row'><label for='cat_page_title'><?php _e('Category Page Title'); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='cat_title' id='cat_title' value='<?php echo $cat_title ?>'>
            <p class='description'><?php _e('Title for the Category '); ?></p>
        </td>
    </tr> <?php
});

add_action ( 'edited_category', function() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['cat_title'] ) )
        update_term_meta( $_POST['tag_ID'], '_pagetitle', $_POST['cat_title'] );
});

  add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ajax_Person' );

  function ajax_Person() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#saveperson").on("click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      person();
    });
    function person(){
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: { action: 'data_person', catName: jQuery('#nameCat').val(), catSurnam: jQuery('#surnameCat').val(), catCity: jQuery('#cityCat').val(), catDob: jQuery('#dobCat').val(), catBio: jQuery('#bioCat').val()  },
        success: function(data) {
          jQuery(".modal-body .help-text").html(data);
        }
      });
    }
    </script>
  <?php }

  add_action('wp_ajax_data_person' , 'data_person');
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_person','data_person');

  function data_person(){
    $catname = $_POST['catName'];
    $surnameCat = $_POST["surnameCat"];
    $cityCat = $_POST["cityCat"];
    $catDob = $_POST["dobCat"];
    $catBio = $_POST["catBio"];
    $cat_ID = get_cat_ID( sanitize_title_for_query($catname) );  
    // Check if category exists
    if($cat_ID == 0) {
      $my_cat = array(
        'cat_name' => $cat_name, 
        'category_description' => $cat_bio, 
        'category_nicename' => $cat_slug, 
        'category_parent' => 0
      );
      $cat_id = wp_insert_category( $my_cat );
      if( ! is_wp_error( $cat_id ) && (int)$cat_id ) {
        // NOW, add the metadata...
        add_term_meta( $cat_id, '_pagetitle', $surnameCat );
        echo json_encode("Category added successfully");
      } else {
        echo json_encode("That category already exists");
      }
    }
    exit;
  }
```

And the html:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="add-pearson-form memory-form">
        <div class="m-form-wrap">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="frm_close"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a>
            <div class="team_person">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                        <h4 class="text-center text-uppercase">aggiungi una persona</h4>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="NOME">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="COGNOME">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="CITTA">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control pickdate" placeholder="DATA DI NASCITA">
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="froala-editor" placeholder=" type ricordo"></textarea>
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <a href="" class="primary-btn text-uppercase">inserisci persona</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @cale_b it isn't saving the value I am sending from the input field once I click. updating the question with this description too. Basically what should I put instead of ` 'cat_title' =>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is to use the [add_term_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_term_meta) function.

Don't insert `cat_title` into the category - the [wp_insert_category](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_category) function doesn't accept / use that argument.

Instead, get the category ID back *from* `wp_insert_category`, then use that ID to add the meta value.

See your modified / simplified code below, with comments explaining changes:

```
    // no need to assign variables here, commented out and using originals below
    // $cat_name = $catname;  
    // $cat_sur = $surnameCat;
    // $cat_city = $cityCat;  
    // $cat_dob = $catDob;
    // $cat_bio = $catBio;
    // $cat_slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes($cat_name);
    $my_cat = array(
      'cat_name'             => $catname, 
      'category_description' => $catBio, 
      // this is a _custom meta field_, so doesn't get inserted here...
      // 'cat_title'            => $cat_sur, 
      'category_nicename'    => sanitize_title_with_dashes($catname), 
      'category_parent'      => 0
    );

    // get the category ID from the insert
    $cat_id = wp_insert_category( $my_cat );
    if( ! is_wp_error( $cat_id ) && (int)$cat_id ) {
      // NOW, add the metadata...
      add_term_meta( $cat_id, '_pagetitle', $surnameCat );
      echo json_encode("Category added successfully");
    } else {
      echo json_encode("That category already exists");
    }
```

Comment: not adding even the cat name now, I have updated the question with the full code if that helps

Comment: In regards of point 2, yes you're right, I just did a copy paste, since I haven't removed the double vars as you suggested.

Comment: if I use the first code in the question, the cat is added but without the custom field, with your nothing is added :(

Comment: basically if I do `if( wp_insert_category( $my_cat ) ) {` on your code works but no custom value is added in the new custom field, but if I do `if( ! is_wp_error( $cat_id ) && (int)$cat_id ) {` won't add anything

Comment: if I try `$cat_id = wp_insert_category( $my_cat );
      if( wp_insert_category( $my_cat ) ) {
      
        add_term_meta( $cat_id, '_pagetitle', $cat_sur );` it adds the category but not the value into the new category custom field

Comment: Where would I display the var_dump tho? It is using ajax and not printing it anywhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183200/discussion-between-rob-m-and-cale-b).